# Can a GraphQLHttpClient be instantiated against an in memory server

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql

Hoping to run integration tests against an in memory server. If I were to create the in-memory server using `WebApplicationFactory<Program>`, how would I instantiate a `GraphQLHttpClient` against it?  The constructors for `GraphQLHttpClient` expect an endpoint.

I know I could run integration tests against an in memory server in dotnet core 7.0  using an `HttpClient` and plain json using the approach described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

I would though, like to use a more [GraphQL centric approach](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client).

I would I set up the integration tests to run purely in memory using the `WebApplicationFactory`?